# How can I convert Hex string to Vec<u8>

Tags: substrate

I want to convert a hexadecimal string obtained as external data to Vec in my pallet.
For that reason, I tried to use "hex::decode", but I get the following compilation error and cannot use it.
Can you tell me a workaround or an alternative?

I got errors following.

```
  error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `pallet_offchain` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `hex` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `std` loaded from /Users/shin.takahashi/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-38314f0df48bc600.rlib
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/shin.takahashi/develop/substrate/newest_node_template/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-33eeda8e29be2065.rmeta

  error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `pallet_offchain` depends on): `oom`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `hex` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `std` loaded from /Users/shin.takahashi/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib/libstd-38314f0df48bc600.rlib
    = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /Users/shin.takahashi/develop/substrate/newest_node_template/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-33eeda8e29be2065.rmeta

  error: aborting due to 2 previous errors; 6 warnings emitted
```

My code is like following.

```
fn get_decoded_address(address:&str)-> Vec<u8> {
    //value of address is like following. "0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d"
    hex::decode(&address).unwrap()
}
```

Comment: I want to receive an AccountId like the one below as a string, assign it to an AccountId on my palette, and send money to that AccountId."0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d"

Comment: You need to import `hex` with `default-features = false`, and then add `hex/std` to your pallet/runtime's `std` feature.

Comment: If this ^^ helps out, you can post it yourself as the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
It works.
And I apologize my lack of reading document of substrate.
I will write the answer later.

Answer (score 2):

I have to write "Cargo.toml" Correctly. following is example.

```
rustc-hex = { version="2.1.0", default-features = false }

[features]
default = ['std']
std = [
    'rustc-hex/std',
]
```